# on hover text in list text-decoration not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an unordered list in which I have a link which has the same background color as the hover on text, so when the particular list is hovered the text is hidden. I am trying to remove that effect from the particular list so that text in it is not hidden.

I did the following:

```html
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="about-us.html">TEIA</a></li>
            <li><a href="services-1.html">Board Members</a></li>
            <li><a href="services-2.html">Agenda</a></li>
            <li><a href="our-event.html">Vision & Mission</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Members</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="portfolio-overlay.html">Membership Type</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio-classic.html">Code of Conduct</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio-overlay.html">Membership Benefits</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio-classic.html">Register/Join</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Resources</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Upcoming Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog-grid.html">Previous Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="single-blog.html">Press Release</a></li>
            <li><a href="single-blog.html">Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li class="nyan" style="background-color: #00bfff; text-decoration: none;">
        <a href="#">Log In</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Admin</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog-grid.html">Members</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But still there is no change in it. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Have you tried like this,  ul > li > a:hover {text-decoration: none;} ?
Orelse, please do specify how did you try, it will be easy to resolve your issue

Comment: `text-decoration` property should be on `a` element, not `li`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use particular class and then `a:hover` to target the text color. check snippet.

```css
li.nyan a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about-us.html">TEIA</a></li>
      <li><a href="services-1.html">Board Members</a></li>
      <li><a href="services-2.html">Agenda</a></li>
      <li><a href="our-event.html">Vision & Mission</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Members</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="portfolio-overlay.html">Membership Type</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio-classic.html">Code of Conduct</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio-overlay.html">Membership Benefits</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio-classic.html">Register/Join</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Resources</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="blog.html">Upcoming Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog-grid.html">Previous Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="single-blog.html">Press Release</a></li>
      <li><a href="single-blog.html">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li class="nyan" style="background-color: #00bfff; text-decoration: none;"><a href="#">Log In</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="blog.html">Admin</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog-grid.html">Members</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i tried what you said like this, when i hover on parent text, its okey, but when i hover on child list, the parent is hiding

Comment: in snippet its not happening so i guess your some css conflicts. in that case you have to add the css to this question so we can see what you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

add some other color to the content when hovered.

```css
.dropdown ul li:hover{
  background: #0056b3;
  color:white;
}
.dropdown ul li:hover a{
 
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown">
<li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                
</li>
<li><a href="#">About</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="about-us.html">TEIA</a></li>
<li><a href="services-1.html">Board Members</a></li>
<li><a href="services-2.html">Agenda</a></li>
<li><a href="our-event.html">Vision & Mission</a></li>

</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Members</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="portfolio-overlay.html">Membership Type</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio-classic.html">Code of Conduct</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio-overlay.html">Membership Benefits</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio-classic.html">Register/Join</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
  <li><a href="#">Resources</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="blog.html">Upcoming Events</a></li>
 <li><a href="blog-grid.html">Previous Events</a></li>
<li><a href="single-blog.html">Press Release</a></li>
<li><a href="single-blog.html">Gallery</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
 <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
 <li class="nyan" style="background-color: #00bfff; text-decoration: none;"><a href="#">Log In</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="blog.html">Admin</a></li>
  <li><a href="blog-grid.html">Members</a></li>
                                                    
 </ul>
 </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: i want to change that particular list color, not all the list

Comment: yes this will change the color of the one which is hovered and not the whole list since i have targeted a tags from li

Comment: i tried what you said like this, when i hover on parent text, its okey, but when i hover on child list, the parent is hiding

Comment: check now..is this how you want it?